# When type = A | B it enables a combination of the two. Can this be prevented?

Tags: mongodb, typescript

I want to be able to say in typescript that a Lookup in mongodb can be either by a key match, or by a pipeline:

```
type Lookup<T> = {
  $lookup:
    | {
        from: keyof typeof Collections;
        localField: string;
        foreignField: string;
        as: string;
      }
    | {
        from: keyof typeof Collections;
        let: { [k: string]: string };
        pipeline: Aggregation<T>[];
        as: string;
      };
};
```

But The result is a combination of both.
I don't want typescript to show me the `pipeline` or `let` option when I already have `localField`.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to clearly separated members of the union we need proper [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). That means that we need to append discriminator which will clearly separate one member from another. Consider such small change to your type definition with property `tag`:

```
type Lookup<T> = {
  $lookup:
    | {
        tag: 'A',
        from: keyof typeof Collections;
        localField: string;
        foreignField: string;
        as: string;
      }
    | {
        tag: 'B',
        from: keyof typeof Collections;
        let: { [k: string]: string };
        pipeline: Aggregation<T>[];
        as: string;
      };
};
```

Thanks to the discriminant `tag` there is no possibility to pass object with mixed values.

---

Discriminated union is the proper way of fixing the issue, but we can also do some magic at the type level. Consider:

```
// simplified types
type A = {
        a: string,
        b: string;
        c: string;
}
type B = {
    a: string,
    d: string,
    e: string    
}
// I also made types as stand alone
type X = A | B

// type which will do the job
type Exclusive<T extends X> = {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof A ? T[K] : never 
} | {
    [K in keyof T]: K extends keyof B ? T[K] : never 
}
// function which allows only for not a mixed valued
function test<T extends X>(x: Exclusive<T>) { return x }
test({
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    d: 'd',
    e: 'e'
}) // error as it is a mix 

test({
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: 'c'
}) // ok not a mix

test({
    a: 'a',
    d: 'd',
    e: 'e'
}) // ok not a mix
```

[The Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=38&ssc=19&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEGcEsFsAcBtIDNIFMAmoAuBPWrwAoXfUAQVAF5QBvQ0BxhgQwC4IsAnSAOwHMANPSaMARu3BdefANzCRoAMYSp-OQF9ieVKABCVWvNBsO3fkKboVZwUdTXpTQpq2kAGgYoAfPYVc6AUQAPRXgAVygAN1QAHgAVUFQgrFQedHBQNwA%20AzomAG0AaVBeUABrVBwAeyRQOIBddmKklLSMiuraigB%20OqL60HYeVGjOUGdQHzzGIpKecsqausbQZuTU9IXOvVBeuP7B0GHR8c0kMJ5FLEgq%20ZTJeMT1tsysgAog9mDQiMho%20KyAEpaKBOKgsGFOPMgqBNPcsG9pix2AByZgoixiVGiDFGKygFHoXFMewE1Ao5zAkCJTicKpjZgZSBYEoZZigaCQGGAXg3ALI7fnhiKMJjRxKxBJxmIYygJigp6ipYCqZSOVRZ7M5QQFBARSOMqPRUtA%20MJYoYpJR5MpoGpytV6o5XKAA)

`Exclusive` allows only on `A` or only `B` by putting all other fields as `never`. In the example I am creating stand alone types from the union, this is because we need to refer to them in `Exclusive` type. You need to do the same and put your types in A and B.

Comment: Thanks! It's good to know, but unfortunately I have to keep the correct syntax and can't add such a key

Comment: The other solution is playing around with type systems dark places. Consider reading this - https://dev.to/macsikora/advanced-typescript-exercises-answer-7-3k5e